# Convert Date in format Day MM DD, Year(e.g Wed Aug 17, 2016) to yyyy-mm-dd in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a date value in the format of `Day MM dd, yyyy` (e.g. `Wed Aug 17, 2016`) in PHP and I want to convert it to the format `yyyy-mm-dd` (`2016-08-dd`).

I have tried following:

```
$journeyDate = 'Wed Aug 17, 2016';
$time =strtotime(stripslashes($journeyDate));
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($time));
```

But the above code converts the date to desired format but returns date as `1970-01-01` which is wrong. What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're applying `strtotime` twice - once when initializing `$time` and once again when applying `date` to it. Remove one of them and you should be OK:

```
$journeyDate = 'Wed Aug 17, 2016';
$time = strtotime(stripslashes($journeyDate));
echo date("Y-m-d", $time);
# Here ------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the`DateTime` Class like so:

```
    <?php

        $journeyDate    = 'Wed Aug 17, 2016';
        $jdObjDT        = new DateTime($journeyDate);

        var_dump($jdObjDT->format("Y-m-d"));
        // PRODUCES::: string '2016-08-17' (length=10)
```